# Weird flow of simple mean stack application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, angularjs-routing

Here is my implementation of simple mean stack application

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlistDB', ['contactlist']);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/friendlist', function(req, res){

    db.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("DB connected !!!");
    });

    console.log("received GET request");
    db.contactlist.find(function(err, docs){
        res.send(docs);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");
    $http.get('/friendlist').success(function(response){
      $scope.friendList = response;
    })
}]);﻿
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<title>Friends Information App</title>
<body>
      <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Friend Information App</h1>

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>         
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friendList"> <!-- same as for loop -->
          <th>{{friend.name}}</th>
          <th>{{friend.email}}</th>
          <th>{{friend.number}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Definitely my route is /friendlist but I do not know why, when I just hit thr url http://localhost:3000, all my friends information are shown up with the UI in index.html file. And when hitting the http://localhost:3000/friendlist, what I got just the json normal text without UI

Please help to explain to me about the workflow of this case.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're hitting http://localhost:3000 you reach your web page which contains all your UI stuff. By hitting http://localhost:3000/friendlist, you're requesting your API which prints your JSON object. This is because you're serving your html by your API with the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`. It's a normal behavior.

Comment: What I know is when we hit the localhost:3000, the index.html file in /public folder is loaded by default (with express.static(...) like I implemented above). But the db connection is defined in /friendlist url, We do not hit that url but the connection to db and the function to send all docs back to controller is up? I'm newbie with mean as well as nodejs and express, Can you explain the flow of this case for me. many thanks.

Comment: Yes, but in your `controller.js` file you call the API route /friendlist which will init your DB as you mentioned. To follow your app steps:
localhost:3000 (index.html) -> Call /friendlist -> Init DB -> Print infos on page.

Comment: So the workflow in this case is.
We hit the localhost:3000 then the index.html is shown up, It is controlled by the controller which will send a request to /friendlist defined in server, and all the things will happen as It will

Comment: Exactly. Basically when you're calling http://locahost:3000/friendlist, you hit directly the Node API so you will see the same data as the `response` object in your controller, you will just have no UI above.

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all 
app.get('/friendlist', function(req, res){

    db.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("DB connected !!!");
    });

    console.log("received GET request");
    db.contactlist.find(function(err, docs){
        res.send(docs);
    });
});

it is called which redirects to the get method in /friendlist controller function.

Under that 
 $http.get('/friendlist').success(function(response){
      $scope.friendList = response;
    })
it is called and it gives the response in friendlist var. and it prints out the thing accordingly.
```